# What is the best way to compare two pip package versions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

Let's say I have two packages, `Django==1.11b1` and `Django==1.11b1custom` installed in two separate virtual environments `env1` and `env2` respectively.

What is the best way to see all of the code change in any of the files within (or in other words the diff of) these two package versions?

**EDIT:** For this scenario I don't have access to the source for the custom package. Though I could create one from the package installation and push, I was hoping there would be an easy way to do this locally since I may never need the newly created repository thereafter.

Comment: I should use a git diff for such comparison

Comment: Best way is if the package [happens to be on Github](https://github.com/django/django/compare/stable/1.10.x). Of course, you could create the repositories locally and then do a `git diff`.

Comment: go to the source repository and compare there.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard So I would have to create a repo for the installed custom package in the installation directory only to make the comparison? Git would work but does not seem ideal in this situation given that the custom version may be discarded after the comparison. I was hoping for some sort of `pip diff Django` or similar, although that of course doesn't work for numerous reasons.